# Win32 .def Forward Export By Ordinal

Tags: visual-studio, winapi, dll, export

For my Visual Studio project, I'm create a .def file for my exported functions, but I would like to create one with forwarded exports by ordinal if that's possible. I know there's a way to create a module definition file that uses forward exports by name, such as:

```
EXPORTS
HeapAlloc = ntdll.RtlAllocateHeap
```

But is there anyway to do forwarding of exports by ordinal, such as:

```
EXPORTS
HeapAlloc = ntdll.@647
```

Comment: need `ntdll.#647` - the `#` symbol must be exactly for ordinal forward, not `@`

Comment: i not sure are this can be done exactly by using def file, but this can be done by using `#pragma comment(linker, "/export:somename=ntdll.#647")` or `__pragma(comment(linker, "/export:somefunc=ntdll.#647"))`

Comment: @RbMm this worked exactly how I needed, thanks!